# Angular 6 http + Observable + Subject across multiple components

Tags: angular, http, get, observable, subscribe

I'm trying to share data that a my service providers retrieves via a HTTP GET. I get data in my `http.service`:

```
@Injectable()
export class HttpService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  public getData4(url: string): Observable<Premium[]> {
    return this.http.get<Premium[]>(url);
  }
}
```

The routing of app is:

```
<TabsComponent>
  <TablesComponent> 
  <TablesComponent/>
</TabsComponent>
```

In tabs.component.ts I have:

```
 export class TabsComponent implements OnInit {

  myUrl4All = 'http://localhost:8083/RCCT-2.0-SNAPSHOT/rest/v2';
  premiumsO: Premium[] = [];

  constructor(private httpService: HttpService, private entity1Service: Entity1Service) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.httpService.getData4(this.myUrl4All).subscribe(data => this.premiumsO = 
    data['premiumList']);
  }
}
```

In my tabs.component.html I have:

```
<div>
<app-tables-component></app-tables-component>
</div>
```

And my tables.component.ts:

```
export class TablesComponent implements OnInit  {

  constructor() { }

  returnedArray: Premium[] = [];

  ngOnInit(): void {

    this.returnedArray = ?????????
  }
```

}

And my question is: now I have one `http.service` with an observable, but I want to catch and display data from http in my `tables.component` by using subscribe. How I should change my code to do that ?

Comment: if your `TabsComponent` is parent and `TablesComponent` is child then you can use `@Input`

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction. Also note that your code doesn't make sense. The service claims that the event emitted by the observable is of type Premium[], and in your component, you're using `data['premiumList']`. Arrays don't have a `premiumList` property.

Comment: For - JB Nizet - I recieve the list of objects from java in JSON. premiumList - the main "wrapper" in my JSON. So, now code it working well!

Comment: It's working well, but it's wrong. You're lying by saying it returns an `Observable<Premium[]>`, since the actual returned type is `Observable<{premiumList: Premium[]}>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One simple and quick way is for you to user `@Input` (remember to import this from `@angular/core`) on your child component like this:

```
export class TablesComponent implements OnInit  {

  constructor() { }

  @Input()
  returnedArray: Premium[] = [];

  ngOnInit(): void { }
}
```

and then on your parent `template.html` pass the parents data like this:

```
<div>
    <app-tables-component [returnedArray]="premiumsO"></app-tables-component>
</div>
```

EDIT: As per comments below

Add your `Array` into your service, make it an observable and subscribe to it. Like:

```
@Injectable()
export class HttpService {
  premiumsO: BehaviorSubject<Premium[]> = new BehaviorSubject<Premium[]>();

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  public getData4(url: string): void {
    this.http.get<Premium[]>(url).subscribe(data => {
        this.premiumsO.next(data['premiumList']);
    });
  }
}
```

And then in both your parent and child controllers, subscribe to `premiumsO` like:

```
export class TablesComponent implements OnInit  {

  constructor(private httpService: HttpService) { }
  private subscription: Subscription;
  returnedArray: Premium[] = [];

  ngOnInit(): void {
       this.subscription = this.httpService.premiumsO.subscribe(data => this.returnedArray =  data);
  }
    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.subscription.unsubscribe().        
    }
}
```

Do the same thing in your parent. Not sure if this is the right solution but I'd do it like this.

Comment: Thanks! I walked this way but I want to try "Subscribe"-version for learning purposes... Can you advice me something about Subscibe implementation in my code?

Comment: Can you simply move the subscription from your `tabs.component.ts` to your `tables.component.ts` instead? Why do you need it in the parent component?

Comment: To Morema - ok, this solution is good. Buuuuut! **What if i want to give user change my Array in tables.component and display part of them in parent component (tabs.component) or in another children component. How I can do it?**

Comment: @AntonRomanov what if you move your array into your service, make it an observable and subscribe to that in both your components? I'll edit and add what I mean

Comment: Thanks a lot! My question is answered. Sorry for stupid question )

Comment: No worries, it's not stupid. We're all learning. Keep it up and good luck :)